# 5x5 table with unique properties

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 |

This 5x5 table has unique properties.
Each number (x) in a cell means:

> The cell is surrounded (including diagonal neighbours) by x unique
> numbers in the squares surrounding it.

Example:
(2,2) cell (red) is 3, so it is surrounded by 3 unique numbers (1,2 and 3)
(4,4) cell (blue) is 4, so it is surrounded by 4 unique numbers (1,2, 3 and 4)

**The Question**

[image]

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | 3 |  |  |

**Fill in the blanks so the table has the same unique properties.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution, with

> entries at most 4. It was found by basic depth-first search with pruning (checking if the neighbouring condition hold at each cell). This is colloquially called as *backtracking*.

Here it comes:

> ```
>  3 2 3 3 3
>  3 4 4 4 2
>  3 4 1 4 3
>  2 4 4 4 3
>  3 3 3 2 3
> ```

Other solutions might be possible. Edit: this is the *unique* solution.

Comment: `Edit: this is the unique solution.` Why?

Comment: @CodeNewbie see edit summary. It is clear that the value in each of the cells is bounded, so this is a finite problem and the only thing you need to do is to check all cases.